# How to copy files from archive to my system, following the directory structure?

Tags: linux, latex, installation-package

I am having trouble figuring out how to install tcolorbox package in my Ubuntu. I have downloaded a .tds.zip file from [its CTAN repository](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) , but this archive does not have a `make` nor an `install` script...

In the README file, the authors make a suggestion:

> Copy the contents of the `tcolorbox.tds.zip` from CTAN to your local TeX file tree.

So I was thought there was an easy way to copy the files to the right places thought the cp command from the terminal, but I just couldn'g really figure it...

Let me be more precise. The archive has a directory structure consisting of two long branches, with a bunch of files hanging in the end of each branch, kind of like this:

*tcolotbox.tds.zip*

- ----->**doc**/latex/tcolorbox/(first bunch of files)*
- ----->**tex**/latex/tcolorbox/(second bunch of files) *

which you can see in the next figure (that's a screenshot from my Archive Manager window). The files in the end of the first branch are supposed to go to one folder somewhere in my TeX file tree, and the second bunch to another folder somewhere else.

[image: archive directory structure:]

(If I am not being clear at this point, would you be so kind as to download the archive from CTAN and have a look at it? :D)

So, my question is:

> Is there a way to copy these files to the right places in my system, following their directory structure?

(Since it seems they are organized to guide the program that will copy them, with the folders inside the archive having the names of the folders that should be somewhere in my system, right?)

Thank you all so much!

Comment: It's been a while since I've had to use command line input and because I've only used certain Linux flavours in college, I'd have to suggest looking into "decompression" techniques because you are not just copying files. The files you are suggesting are zipped, so there should be some kind of command for that I suppose. I could be wrong, but maybe that line of logic would help. I have a feeling you will have to create a tmp folder for decompression. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome on Super User. Try the suggestions proposed and come back to give as some feedback. On your own question's page you can write comments to your question and to the answers.

Comment: Hastur's answer solved my question! I just needed two slight modifications: (1) copy the files to the _texmf_ folder inside usr/ **local** /share instead of usr/share (I needed to make the directory structure with _mkdir_ before copying...); (2) update the _ls-R_ file that was already inside that folder with the command _sudo mktexlsr_

Thanks a lot for your time, Hastur!

Comment: Btw this is where I found about the _ls-R_ update: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/how-can-i-manually-install-a-latex-package-debian-ubuntu-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my system (Ubuntu 14.04 + texlive), this package is under the main directories of `texlive` in

```
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/tcolorbox
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox
```

Usually the packages styles are under `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/PACKAGEDIR` and the doc below `/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/PACKAGEDIR`.

If you have a different Latex/Linux distribution the directory may be different, but not its structure.

- Download the package
- unzip it `unzip tcolorbox.tds.zip` in a temporary directory

  ```
  .
  ├── doc
  │   └── latex
  │       └── tcolorbox
  └── tex
      └── latex
          └── tcolorbox
  ```
- Then copy the 2 directories in the relative paths

  ```
  sudo cp -rpi ./doc/latex/tcolorbox  /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/tcolorbox
  sudo cp -rpi ./tex/latex/tcolorbox  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox
  ```

**Notes**:

- If you put the style in the directory of your file it should work (only for that directory, it can be cosy if you work on many environment and you cannot set all, if you give the file to someone in this conditions, if you need to use a specific version different from the installed one).
- If you put in a different directory (e.g. `./sty`) you can set an environment variable `TEXINPUTS=".:./sty:"` <sup>[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22015390/3569208)]</sup> then run pdflatex.
- Usually you can add packages (or bunch of packages) from the system (e.g. in Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install ...` or with `tlmgr package_name` or with `tlmgr --gui` ... )
- You should know your latex version and search for the path in which it is installed on your system in the man or in the documentation. BTW to find the main directory where the packages are installed you can play a little with Linux ...

  ```
  locate *.sty| awk '{print "dirname $(dirname "$1")"}'| sh | sort | uniq -c|sort -n
  ```

  With high probability the entry with the higher number is your path. Use a `| grep doc` to put in evidence the doc one...

Comment: I tried this procedure, but it did not work at first... After some more searching, I found people recommending to put manually installed packages under the /usr/ **local** /share/texmf directory. So I followed your procedure with this other folder (I had to create the folder structure first with mkdir), and it worked after updating the _ls-R_ file that was already inside it (with _sudo mktexlsr_)! Thank you so much for your time, Hastur!

Comment: Also, this _locate|awk_ command was really helpful, I would have never figured what the right folder was without it... That was a really sweet trick! Would you mind explaining it a little?

Comment: @mfernandes You're welcome. There are many places where you can put your package and they are system and _Latex distribution_ dependent. In general you should individuate your version and read the instruction for that version. That line was a lazy workaround written _"on the fly"_. You want to install a `*sty` file. `locate *sty`, if updatedb is installed, answers you with the list of all the sty installed (that updatedb stored). The pipe (`|`) takes the output of the previous command and redirect as input of the following. `awk` writes for each line the command `dirname /path/to/file`. (%)

Comment: (%) Each package is installed in its subdir, so I need 2 `dirname` (the second one executed in a subshell `()` returned as variable to the first `$()`) , `sh` execute each line, `sort` put them in order, `uniq -c` write only one line with the number that is repeated, the last `sort -n` order the output  from the number (-n) more little to the bigger. So you have the number of `*.sty` in each grandfather  directory, that is the place where you have to copy your directory. It's not so well written, but it follows the steps I've done to search for it... a Linux _train_ of commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to unzip the file. The gzip application unzip the file directory's tree as you see it in the preview. Then you can copy paste from nautilus (ubuntu file manager) or use the terminal. Oh and check if you have write access to the directory you are writting to.